# How to get the hold item index of LongListSelector in C# WP silverlight development?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'd like to have an option to delete items from a `longlistselector` when the user holds on an item.

However, getting the `ID` in the Hold listener is not working, (I'm using `ListSelector.ItemsSource.IndexOf(ListSelector.SelectedItem)` to get it). It may not work, because the selection event is not fired as long as the user clicks on it, am I right?

It works, if I click on the item first (it shows an article from the web), but I'd like to solve it - if there's a possible way - without the need of viewing the article first.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void holdClickListener(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
    yourObject selectedItem = (yourObject)element.DataContext;
    int selectionIndex = yourLongListSelector.ItemsSource.IndexOf(selectedItem);
}
```

this should solve your problem.